# Is it possible to create a hierarchical tree of config sets in STS?

Tags: eclipse, spring, configuration-files, spring-tool-suite

I'm working on a Spring application comprised of over 60 projects. I've imported the projects into the eclipse Spring Tool Suite IDE. In my (xml) Spring config files, I have lots of warnings for references to beans that are defined in other Spring config files, saying for example

> Referenced bean 'myService' not found

I can fix this by creating a Spring config set containing both files, but there are many such dependencies between the many Spring config files. It feels like I should be able to create a hierarchical tree of config sets, but I can't figure out how to do that in STS. (It looks like it is possible [in IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-file-sets.html#parent-child).)

Is it possible to create a hierarchical tree of config sets in STS?

If so, how? I can't find much documentation on this - where should I look?

If not, all I can think of is adding all the files to one big config set. Is this the right thing to do? Or does it mean that our config files are too inter-dependent and ought to be refactored?

Edit: It seems that a config set is not visible outside its project. So they won't work in this multi-project set-up. Also, once I've created a config set, I cannot work out how to delete it (without directly editing the .springBeans file) - any ideas on how to delete a config set (just the set, not the config files that it contains)?

Comment: You can create one main config file and then you can import the remaining config files in it in the order you want to using `<import resource="Spring-beans.xml" />`

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera Yes, imports works, but I was hoping to use config sets. (Just as a learning exercise, really.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring IDE validations run against the Spring config files that you configure in the project preferences.

If you don't use the import statement in your config files to define their dependencies, you need to add the necessary config files to that preference dialog, so that the Spring IDE knows which config files to use and analyze. For this case you don't need config sets, I think. But this mechanism doesn't work across projects.

You can also combine those two mechanisms, if that makes sense to you: use import of config files where you are that relationship, and configure the root config files in the project preferences (directly or via config sets).

Config sets are, unfortunately, not hierarchical at the moment. I am just not sure at the moment whether we should make config sets hierarchical, or should allow simple config files to be configured across projects, or maybe both.

I've opened a JIRA ticket (https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4343) to discuss this further. Please feel free to follow that ticket. Maybe you could even provide a few sample projects that would help us to see that would be useful and what not.